# How do I toggle a boolean array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, boolean, toggle

Say I have the following array:

```
[True, True, True, True]
```

How do I toggle the state of each element in this array?

Toggling would give me:

```
[False, False, False, False]
```

Similarly, if I have:

```
[True, False, False, True]
```

Toggling would give me:

```
[False, True, True, False]
```

I know the most straightforward way to toggle a boolean in Python is to use "not" and I found some examples on stackexchange, but I'm not sure how to handle it if its in an array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `not` is still the best way.  You just need a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to go with it:

```
>>> x = [True, True, True, True]
>>> [not y for y in x]
[False, False, False, False]  
>>> x = [False, True, True, False]
>>> [not y for y in x]
[True, False, False, True]
>>>
```

---

I'm pretty sure my first solution is what you wanted.  However, if you want to alter the original array, you can do this:

```
>>> x = [True, True, True, True]
>>> x[:] = [not y for y in x]
>>> x
[False, False, False, False]
>>>
```

Comment: @user2957365:  Note that this does not toggle the original list.  It returns a new list.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski - I'm pretty sure the OP just worded his post wrong and actually wanted my first solution.  But, in case he didn't, I added another.

Comment: @iCodez:  It was not a criticism, just an FYI.  If he wants to alter the original list, assignment to a slice is the way to go:  `x[:] = [not y for y in x]`.  If he wants to affect a local name, simple assignment is the way to go: `x = [not y for y in x]`.

Answer (score 3):

In pure python, with a list comprehension

```
>>> x = [True, False, False, True]
>>> [not b for b in x]
[False, True, True, False]
```

Or, you may consider using numpy arrays for this functionality:

```
>>> x = np.array(x)
>>> ~x
array([False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 2):

@iCodez's answer with list comprehension is more pythonic. I'll just add one other way of doing it:

```
>>> a = [True, True, True, True]
>>> print map(lambda x: not x, a)
[False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: -0.  I'm a fan of `map`, but not a fan of `map` with lambdas.  That's better handled by a list comprehension with no lambda.

Comment: Agreed, python's list comprehension is far more *beautiful* and *pythonic* as compared to map with lambda. I put this in only as one another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

For boolean arrays with more than 1 axis, this will result in a ValueError due to ambiguity.

```
x = np.logical_not(x)
```

2023, Python version 3.7.4, numpy version 1.21.6